# Reasonable SO newbie question deleted - can undelete?

Tags: support, specific-question, specific-answer, undelete-request

A colleague (David Watson) using SO answered this question:

[WiX 3.8 MSI for a 32-bit and a 64-bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018103/wix-3-8-msi-for-32bit-and-64bit-machine/21023262)

And it was deleted for the questionable crime of including not only what looks like a reasonable and succinct answer to the question, but also  a query to the OP about the question.

Since he has 20 rep I don't know if he even had the right to the recommended alternative - comments on the question.

Query part of his answer since removed, can someone reinstate the answer?

Comment: that answer doesn't look deleted to me.

Comment: ... not that it matters all that much, but why is he not asking this?

Comment: @KateGregory Shog works fast.

Comment: We'll now I know how to do it, I'll tell him, and he can handle it for himself next time.  Let's call it PR.

Comment: OOInterest, could I have fixed this myself and how?

Comment: Nope @AlexBrown. I think David could have flagged for moderator attention, but that's about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've restored it. As Bart noted in the comments here, your friend could've flagged the answer for moderator attention and requested a review of the deletion that way as well - this is always a good idea when you've corrected a problem *or* feel a mistake was made.

I'll also see if I can figure out why the reviewer's comment was duplicated thrice:

[image: This does not provide an answer to the question]

Update: reviewer had too much coffee, tried to morse-code the comment using the delete button.

Comment: Thanks, would it have been deleted if the reviewer hadn't got 3 bites of the pie?

Comment: Probably - lots of other people flagged it too, and I suspect the moderator handling it just wasn't paying close enough attention. It just looked extra-crappy with the duplicate comments, which aren't *supposed* to happen.

Comment: Did David even have the right to do what the reviewer suggests (ask OP in comment)? If not, this flag seems cruel and unusual punishment.

Comment: The comment did note that he would need to gain sufficient reputation in order to do this.

Comment: Fair enough, I dont know how to view it now.